# Average absolute value of sum with Rademacher random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, binomial-coefficients, random-variables

Let $a_1, \ldots, a_n $ be independent Rademacher random variables with distribution $P(a_i=1) = P(a_i=-1) = \frac 12$. Estimate from below $$E \left|\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right|.$$

I've reduced this problem to the next one (for even $n$):

Estimate from below following $$\frac 1{2^{n-1}} \left(\sum_{k=n/2}^n kC_n^k - \sum_{k=0}^{n/2}kC_n^k\right).$$

Answer (score 5):

We don't need to estimate it ... we can find the exact solution.

If $Z$~Bernoulli($\frac12$), then $X=2Z-1$ has a Rademacher distribution where $X=-1$ or $1$ with equal probability. Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ denote indepedent Rademacher random variables. Then, the pmf of:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n X_i  =  (2 \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i) - n = 2 Y -n$$

where $Y$~ $Binomial(n,\frac12)$ (since the sum of $n$ Bernoulli's is $Binomial(n,p)$).

Let random variable $Y$ have pmf $f(y)$:

[image]

Then, the expectation we seek, namely, $E[ \left|  \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right|]$ can be found as $E[ \left|  2 Y - n \right|]$, derived here using `mathStatica` (of which I am one of the authors):

[image]

All done.

Here is a plot of the solution as $n$ increases from 1 to 100:

[image]

---

**Monte Carlo check**

When using computer algebra systems (or indeed working manually), it is always good practise to check one's work using alternative methods. For example, when $n = 130$, the exact solution derived above yields:

```
sol /. n -> 130.
```

> 9.07981

Here is a quick Monte Carlo 'check' in *Mathematica*  ... when $n = 130$, we generate 100000 samples, each containing the sum of 130 Rademacher random variables, sum them up, take the absolute value, and compute the sample mean:

```
Mean[Table[ 
              Abs[Total[Table[RandomChoice[{-1, 1}], {130}]]], 
           {100000}]] // N
```

> 9.07358

:)

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used any computer mathematical systems. What does $Binomial (n, Floor [\frac n2])$ mean? If I'm not wrong, the second variable is probiblity and must be in the [0,1]?

And how to prove it theoretically?

Comment: `Binomial[n,m]` is just the standard binomial coefficient (not to be confused with the $Binomial(n,p)$ distribution). ... For more detail on the `Binomial[n,m]` coefficient, see, for instance:  [link](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Binomial.html). As to how to prove it theoretically, do you mean: how to do the required sum manually?

Comment: I should have added that `Floor[x]` gives the greatest integer less than or equal to x. So, `Floor[7.6]` returns 7.

Comment: Yes, I mean how ahndly prove that the required sum equals to $2^{1-n} \mbox{Binomial} \left[n, 1 + \mbox{Floor} \left[\frac n2\right] \right] \left(1+ \mbox{Floor} \left[\frac n2 \right]\right)$